# Excel VBA Goalseek

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to leverage the goalseek command in VBA in an excel spreadsheet.  I have a value in F3, F7, and F18.  When I change the value in F3 I get this error back:

Run-time error '1004':
Reference is not valid

Here is the code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
With Worksheets("Mdl")
If Target = Range("F3") Then

    Range("F3").GoalSeek Goal:=Range("F7"), ChangingCell:=Range("F18")


End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to leverage the `With Worksheets("Mdl")` statement you must add a "." before each `Range`: `.Range("F3").GoalSeek...`

Comment: To add to @Porcupine911's comment - if you don't use the `.` before the `Range` (or `Cells()`, `Rows()`,`Columns()`), there's no point in using `With`, as far as I know.

Comment: I took out the With  Worksheets but am still getting the same error                       Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target = Range("F3") Then


Range("F3").GoalSeek Goal:=Range("F7").Value, ChangingCell:=Range("F18")
    
    
End If

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

The Goalseek requires a formula in the cell you are creating it, so if you change the Range("F3") for a value instead of a formula the error will appear.

Comment: Thanks!  That seems to have helped along with Bruce and Pocupine911's answers